# Is there a limit of a maximum of 7 steps for "Function" "andThen()" "apply()" of Java?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I have the following code -

```
        Function<String, String> step1 = string -> string + " wakes up";
        Function<String, String> step2 = string -> string + "\nbrushes teeth";
        Function<String, String> step3 = string -> string + "\ngoes to toilet";
        Function<String, String> step4 = string -> string + "\ntakes a shower";
        Function<String, String> step5 = string -> string + "\nfeeds the cat";
        Function<String, String> step6 = string -> string + "\ncleans litter box";
        Function<String, String> step7 = string -> string + "\neats breakfast";
        Function<String, String> step8 = string -> string = "\ngoes for work";
        
        String name = "Neha";
```

```
System.out.println(step1.andThen(step2).andThen(step3).andThen(step4).andThen(step5).andThen(step6).andThen(step7).apply(name));
```

gives me output -

```
Neha wakes up
brushes teeth
goes to toilet
takes a shower
feeds the cat
cleans litter box
eats breakfast
```

But,

```
System.out.println(step1.andThen(step2).andThen(step3).andThen(step4).andThen(step5).andThen(step6).andThen(step7).andThen(step8).apply(name));
```

Gives me output -

```
goes for work
```

So, I am wondering if there is a maximum limit of 7 steps here.

I am using Open JDK 11

Comment: Look carefully, `step8` is different from every other step. Did you make a typo or is that intentional?

Comment: Why would I make any such intentional mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Look at this:

```
Function<String, String> step8 = string -> string = "\ngoes for work";
```

Notice the assignment operator `=` instead of append `+`.

Change it to:

```
Function<String, String> step8 = string -> string + "\ngoes for work";
```

and it should show desired results.

Why would Java randomly limit it to 7 steps??